# Is it possible to move your questions from one Stack Exchange site to another?

Tags: support, migration

I posted a question on unix.stackexchange.com which was Ubuntu and Windows related, but later found out about Ask Ubuntu. This might not be possible, but is there a way I can move my question? Or request my question to not get deleted and get it moved to Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flag your question for moderator attention and in the reason ask for it to be migrated. No guarantee it will be (the mod will likely ask the mods on the other site if your question is suitable and hasn't already been asked) but if the other site is happy to accept it then the moderator will migrate it for you.