# I'd like someone to move a question to other SE site (or should I cross post?)

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702247/what-are-my-options-when-i-want-to-restructure-mediawiki-content) which doesn't really belong to this site. I don't have sufficient rights to move this question to where it belongs. Cross-posting is not a good practice eighter.

Could someone with sufficient clearance migrate this question to webapps.stackexchange.com, please?

Comment: Flag it using the flag link below the question, and note that you'd like a moderator to migrate it. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance)

Comment: See this post (among others) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173151/is-it-possible-to-move-your-questions-from-one-stack-exchange-site-to-another

Comment: Executive summary: remember that flags aren't just for *bad things*. Use them anytime you need the assistance of a moderator. Just be sure to explain clearly what you want and why you think it should be done.